# GenericContainer do not pickup files for processing

Tags: java, junit, testcontainers

GenericContainer do not process files while running outside Testcontainers works fine

Seems that container is somehow constrained, not enough resources or somehow blocked, or file watching behaves not properly with bind.

```
public class SimpleIntegrationTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleIntegrationTest.class);

    @Rule
    public GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer<>(
            new ImageFromDockerfile()
                    .withDockerfileFromBuilder(builder ->
                            builder
                                    .from("ourproduct:latest")
                                    .workDir("/opt/ourproduct")
                                    .entryPoint("./Scripts/start.sh")
                                    .build()))
            .withExposedPorts(8080)
            .withFileSystemBind("/home/greg/share", "/share", BindMode.READ_WRITE)
            .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostName("somehost.com"))
            .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*Ourproduct is Up.*\\n", 1).withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)));

    @Test
    public void simpleExchangeTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        LOGGER.info("Starting simple exchange test...");

        // copy input file
        InputStream request = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("message.txt");
        File target = new File("/home/greg/share/input/message.txt");
        FileUtils.copyToFile(request, target);
        FileUtils.touch(target);

        // watch for response
        Path path = Paths.get("/home/greg/share/output");
        WatchService watchService = path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        LOGGER.info("Waiting up to [{}] seconds for response file...", 30);
        WatchKey watchKey = watchService.poll(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (watchKey != null) {
            watchKey.pollEvents().stream().forEach(event -> LOGGER.info(event.context().toString()));
        }

        LOGGER.info("Container logs...");
        LOGGER.info(container.getLogs());

    }
}
```

Obviously I am expecting response in `/home/greg/share/output` but it never arrives.

**Works just fine when I do:**

1. `docker run -itd --name cont --hostname somehost.com -p 8080:8080 --mount type=bind,source=/home/greg/share,target=/share ourproduct:latest`
2. `docker exec -it cont bash`

**In container**

3. `cd /opt/ourproduct`
4. `./Scripts/start.sh`

**Outside container on host**

5. `cp message.txt /home/greg/share/input/`

After few seconds I have response in `home/greg/share/output`
Not the case for `TestContainers`...

**EDIT: When I add in the test:**

```
Container.ExecResult execResult = container.execInContainer("./Scripts/status.sh");
```

**I get:**

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.ConflictException: {"message":"Container aac697315e3e22ccee4cdf805e6b1b325663bae054ab1104021c4da724cb4a5a is not running"}
```

Any idea what is wrong and why it is not running?

Comment: Can it be a file permissions issue?

Comment: Container run on root.. so probably not. But what is the difference anyway between CLI and Testcontainers in this case...

Comment: when I add 

Container.ExecResult execResult = gtFrame.execInContainer("./Scripts/status.sh");

I get com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.ConflictException: {"message":"Container aac697315e3e22ccee4cdf805e6b1b325663bae054ab1104021c4da724cb4a5a is not running"}
How is that possible, what could be a reason?

Comment: Could it be that the container exits immediately for some reason? That would explain why you don't get your output file.

Comment: for CLI I use -itd option for that thus container stays.. how to get the same in TestContainers? seems there is problem in my code. Same behavior for following:

   ` @Rule
    public GenericContainer test = new GenericContainer<>("ubuntu:16.04")
            .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostName("the-cache"));
Container.ExecResult execResult0 = test.execInContainer("ls", "-al", "/");
`

Comment: The difference is that when you run docker directly you actually run bash with a TTY. So the container is running until you exit the shell. In the test you instead build an image and then run a container based on that. So as soon as your status.sh is done it stops the container. I suspect that status.sh exits before your test copies the input file into the container.

Comment: That is most probably correct. How to fix it and keep container running during the tests?

Comment: @GregorzM That's entirely dependent on your application. The container store as soon as the processes started by your status.sh stops

Comment: Then how to run this simple "ls -al /" on Ubuntu from TestContainers? this doesn't work as well...

Answer (score 0):

adding tail solved the problem

```
.entryPoint("./Scripts/start.sh && tail -f /dev/null")
```

Comment: This is not related to your post/question. I see that you have some experience with using TestContainers, just wanted to see if anything ring a bell seeing my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674613/reading-a-file-from-resources-not-working-in-gitlab-ci/56674956?noredirect=1#comment99918207_56674956