# Reading a file from resources not working in gitlab CI

Tags: java, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, testcontainers

I am getting an error while running tests on gitlab CI using the command:

```
./gradlew clean test
```

I am using test containers to run my tests: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/docker_compose/

Here is the code I am using to load the docker compose file which is at src/test/resources.

```
@ClassRule
public static DockerComposeContainer container = new DockerComposeContainer(new File(BaseServiceTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("docker-compose.yml").getFile()));
```

It runs fine when I run locally, buy when running ci on gitlab, I get the following error:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-06-17T18:47:44.903Z","level":"ERROR","thread":"Test worker","logger":"docker[docker/compose:1.8.0]","message":"Log output from the failed container:\n.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/builds/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx-xxxx/src/test/resources/docker-compose.yml'\n","context":"default"}
```

Following is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
include:
  - project: 'xxxx/xxxx/sdlc'
    file: '/sdlc.yml'

variables:
  CONTAINER_NAME: xxxx-xxxx

test:
  stage: test
  image: registry.xxxx.com/xxxx-alpine-jdk8:v1_8_181
  script:
    - ls -la src/test/resources
    - ./gradlew clean test -i
```

In my script, I have `ls -la src/test/resources` and I can see the `docker-compose.yml` file when that script is run. Not sure why it is not available when running the code.

Comment: can you share your gitlab-ci.yml? What image are you using for running your pipeline?

Comment: @earandap I added the gitlab-ci.yml file.

Comment: Did you managed to find an answer? I'm getting a very similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Testcontainers docs [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/gitlab_ci/).
DinD service is required for Testcontainers on Gitlab CI

Here an example:

```
# DinD service is required for Testcontainers
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  # Instruct Testcontainers to use the daemon of DinD.
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  # Improve performance with overlayfs.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

test:
 image: gradle:5.0
 stage: test
 script: ./gradlew test
```

Comment: Expose your local docker port for accepting remote connections and configure the DOCKER_HOST  variable with your IP address, just to be sure that Gitlab is properly set.